# How to count the number of images on a certain page using Mechanize?

Tags: ruby, mechanize

I'm using Mechanize in a Rails 4 application. I created a new `agent` to scrape a page:

```
clienturl = @bid.mozs.where(is_main: true).first.attributes['url']
agent = Mechanize.new
@page = agent.get('http://' + clienturl)
@url = @page.uri
```

I can do things like get the uri, title and meta description. I'd like to now get the count of images on the page and how many of those images are missing alt attributes. Is this possible with Mechanize?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like this:

```
require 'mechanize'

agent = Mechanize.new
page = agent.get('http://www.iana.org/domains/reserved')
doc = page.parser

img_count = doc.search('img').size # => 2
img_w_alt_count = doc.search('img[@alt]').size # => 1
img_count - img_w_alt_count # => 1
```

[Nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org) is the parser inside Mechanize. `parser` returns an instance of the parsed DOM. From that we can ask Nokogiri to `search` for all nodes matching a selector. I used a CSS selector, but you can use XPath also; CSS tends to be more readable and less verbose.

`search` returns a NodeSet, so `size` tells us how many nodes matched.

Comment: or just `page.search('img:not([alt])').size`

Comment: @pguardiario Wow! Yes! Perfect and simple!

Comment: @theTinMan Excellent! Great explanation! That helps me a lot!